# Implementing template operator<< for std::pair<const char*, std::optional<T>> with Handling of Constant Values

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I'm trying to write a template that implements `operator<<` for `std::pair<const char*, std::optional<T>>`. This operator is already implemented for types passed by value or passed by constant reference, as shown in the examples below:

```cpp
MyStream& operator<<(MyStream&, std::pair<const char*, int>);
MyStream& operator<<(MyStream&, std::pair<const char*, const MyClass&>);
```

Now, I'm faced with the challenge of determining whether to use the operator for a value or a constant reference. I've explored two approaches to address this issue. The first approach involves using `if constexpr` to handle different types individually, like so:

```cpp
if constexpr (std::is_same<T, int>::value || std::is_same<T, bool>::value) {
  os << std::pair<const char*, T>{t.first, *t.second};
} else {
  os << std::pair<const char*, const T&>{t.first, *t.second};
}
```

The second approach involves implementing overload functions with priority to determine the appropriate operator to use:

```cpp
template <std::size_t N>
struct overloadPriority : overloadPriority<N - 1> {};

template <>
struct overloadPriority<0> {};

template <typename T>
void serialize(overloadPriority<1>, MyStream& os, const char* key, const T& value) {
  os << std::pair<const char*, const T&>{key, value};
}

template <typename T>
void serialize(overloadPriority<0>, MyStream& os, const char* key, const T& value) {
  os << std::pair<const char*, T>{key, value};
}
```

My question is twofold: First, is there a way to handle constant values like `std::pair<const char*, const int>` (*without reference*), which could be interpreted as either a constant reference or a value? Second, out of curiosity, are there any alternative approaches to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Serialize using only const ref works [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dY87aqqGY). there would be an implicit copy/conversion from `pair<const char*, const int&>` to `pair<const char*, int>`.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I was searching for the problem in slightly the wrong place. The real problem lies with another template that better suits the type. I'll write my answer in the evening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the original question, I mistakenly asked about the wrong aspect of the problem. I was attempting to address the question of implicit conversion, but the actual issue lies in another template that handles overloads my implementation for basic types.

```cpp
// MyStream& operator<<(MyStream&, const MyClass&) must be implemented
MyStream& operator<<(MyStream& os, std::pair<const char*, const MyClass&> value) {
    MyStream block;
    block << value.second;
    os << std::pair<const char*, const MyStream&>{value.first, block};
}
```

This function enables the serialization of data as a new block, provided that I can serialize data into an opened block. The problem arises from the fact that `std::optional<T>::value()` returns a `const T&`, for example, `std::optional<int>` returns `const int&`. This type is overloaded by the template mentioned above rather than the implemented `MyStream& operator<<(MyStream&, std::pair<const char*, int>)`.

To solve this problem, one must check for the existence of the function. In C++20, this can be achieved using [`requires`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints). However, since I am using C++17, I need to resort to SFINAE. I found some useful information about this issue in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/templated-check-for-the-existence-of-a-class-member-function).

Comment: So, deferencing your optional is the issue. Why not let the template argument be an optional? You could then serialize inside the operator without sfinae